# How to Implement Session in a Desktop Java Swing Application that connects with an online database

Tags: java, swing

I have a Java Swing Application that contains multiple Jpanel's with queries inside to manipulate data that is found on a mysql online database. I need a mechanism to implement session to this application so I can log out the user when his idle. Also am searching if i can store user activities when he's using the application in db table for example so I can go through them if something happen and know what the user has done! I know how to do the db part but I need someone to tell me how I can implement the SESSION and get the USER ACTIVITIES

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class with static attributes to store user information when they connect, and you can add a field in the user table that contains the state of the user , when the user connects to online state otherwise when he disconnected to the state line hore

Comment: aha but how I can get the user information, I mean how I could know what buttons or queries did the user use when he's using the app?

Comment: each button has a name and an event , you can know all that has made the user if you manage the events of cliques or another event